# File observer is not working on usbpath

Tags: android, usb, fileobserver

File observer is working fine with external SD Card ,internal storage ,  but it doesn't work with usb drive (/storage/usbotg)

Comment: Share some code. What did you try? Why is it not working? It is impossible for anyone to help you with this information

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK If it is mounted via USB storage then in android it will not work. `FileObserver` event wont work when the storage is mounted.

However you can check on Android 3.0+.It uses [Media Transfer Protocol (MTP)](http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/) instead of USB storage so `FileObserver` will work on newer versions of OS.